# GDB autoinitialising variables

Tags: debugging, memory, gdb

I am trying to do an example about memory management in C++. I want to show people that there always is something standing in the memory (even if you do not write anything in it)

My problem is that `gdb` seems to exactly  delete this values for debugging purpose...

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe8f8) at dangling.cpp:6
6       int *test=new int;
(gdb) n
8       *test=10;
(gdb) p *test
$1 = 0
(gdb) n
10      delete test;
(gdb) p *test
$2 = 10
(gdb) n
12      std::cout<<*test<<std::endl;
(gdb) p *test
$3 = 0
(gdb)
```

is there a way to tell `gdb` not to do that. I would like to see the real value in the memory instead of the `0` of `$1` and `$3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> gdb seems to exactly delete this values for debuging purpouse.

GDB does *nothing* of the sort.

> I would like to see the real value in the memory instead of the 0 of $1 and $3

You *are* seeing the real value in memory (which happens to be 0).

Your problem is that default heap allocation returns you "clean" memory. It's only on subsequent re-allocations that you'll likely see "dirty" memory.

Comment: Thank you but i am not sure how i get dirty memory from g++ then